# Displaying images from Firebase DB that's stored in Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am making a fitness android application and I am storing progress images of Users using the Firebase Storage. A reference to the Firebase Database is also made with the URL of the image thats found in Firebase Storage.

I am attempting to retrieve the images and show them in a GridLayout but am recieveing a 'Bound to Type Error'

I am displaying the images using a recyclerView.
I am also using Picasso to load the image.

**Photo Activity**

```
public class PhotosActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.activity_photos_fab)
    FloatingActionButton newPhoto;

    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activity_photos_recyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK)    {

            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Uploading..");
            mProgressDialog.show();

            // Get the URI of the photo
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Photos").child(userEmail).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            Firebase photosReference = new Firebase(Utils.FIRE_BASE_PHOTOS_REFERENCE + userEmail);

            // Add the photo to the database
            // if successful then show a toast to say a photo has been added
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You added a photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            String photoURL = filepath.getDownloadUrl().toString();

            bus.post(new PhotoService.AddPhotoRequest(photoURL, userEmail));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Firebase photosReference = new Firebase(Utils.FIRE_BASE_PHOTOS_REFERENCE + userEmail);

        Query sortQuery = photosReference.orderByKey();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Photo, PhotoViewHolder>(Photo.class,
            R.layout.list_individual_photo,
            PhotoViewHolder.class,
            sortQuery) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PhotoViewHolder photoViewHolder, Photo photo, int i) {
                photoViewHolder.populate(PhotosActivity.this, photo);
            }
        };

        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 4);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        adapter.cleanup();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.activity_photos_fab)
    public void setNewPhoto()   {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
    }
}
```

**PhotoViewHolder**

```
public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.list_individual_photo_imageView)
    ImageView photoImage;

    @BindView(R.id.list_individual_photo_progressBar)
    ProgressBar photoProgressBar;

    public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void populate (Context context, Photo photo) {
        itemView.setTag(photo);

    Picasso.with(context).load(photo.getPhotoURl())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(photoImage, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    photoProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });
    }
}
```

**LivePhotoService**

```
public class LivePhotoService extends BaseLiveService {

    @Subscribe
    public void getPhotos(final PhotoService.GetPhotoRequest request) {
        final PhotoService.GetPhotoResponse response = new PhotoService.GetPhotoResponse();

        response.valueEventListener = request.firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                response.photo = dataSnapshot.getValue(Photo.class);
                if(response.photo != null)  {
                    bus.post(response);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(application.getApplicationContext(), firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Photo Object**

```
public class Photo {

    private String photoID;
    private String photoURl;
    private HashMap<String, Object> photoDate;
    private String ownerEmail;

    public Photo(String photoID, String photoURl, HashMap photoDate, String ownerEmail) {
        this.photoID = photoID;
        this.photoURl = photoURl;
        this.photoDate = photoDate;
        this.ownerEmail = ownerEmail;
    }

    public String getPhotoID() {
        return photoID;
    }

    public String getPhotoURl() {
        return photoURl;
    }

    public HashMap getPhotoDate() {
        return photoDate;
    }

    public String getOwnerEmail() {
        return ownerEmail;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Firebase-UI Android library which gives you ability to load images from storage ref directly. In your case it would look something like this

I'm not sure if Picasso is supported but you can use Glide
For example:

```
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

Glide.with(this /* context */)
    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
    .load(mStorageRef + "/Photos/" + userId)
    .error(R.drawable.default)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I want to store the date of the photo uploaded though thats why I'm storing the URL in the database and then calling the reference. Is this still possible doing it directly? @IvanMilisavljevic

Comment: Not sure i understand you

Comment: So when a user uploads a photo, I also timestamp it so that I can display the date and time they uploaded the photo.
So currently when a user adds a photo from their gallery, it takes in the storage url and date, id etc and stores it into the database, then the adapter displays the photo with the date they uploaded it @IvanMilisavljevic